# EF Core 5.0 DB first approach to access DB for read purpose

Tags: database, entity-framework-core

I am developing an application with Asp.Net core 5 and the application accesses and displays information from two different databases(both Sql). One database is application’s own database where all the information will be stored/added. But there is another database already exists(on-prem server) and being used by another application. I want to read some master data from this database to use in my application. So I want to connect to the second database to just read master data and display it in application pages. For the first database connectivity I have created a separate entity project using Entity Framework Core 5.0 Code first approach.

How do I access second database just for read data purpose, Which would be the feasible approach for this. I was thinking to create another entity project with EF Core 5 DB first approach, but with this approach it creates DBContext class and all DbSets objects for each table. Which is not required I feel because I just want to read 8-10 tables from the entire database

Can anyone please suggest which would be a better approach for this? DB first approach or Ado.Net Vanilla method?

Finally I am going to reference these entity projects into my Web API application for all DB operations.

Thanks!

Comment: Use EF Core Power Tools, it lets you choose which tables/views to include, and log on to the reference database as a user that can only read data.

Answer (score 0):

Within the same project, next to your existing dbContext, register a new extension of db context that will encapsulate the second database that you want to read from.

Do not copy the entire project from the start, rather think that the only reason to have a second dbContext to start with, is when dealing with multiple databases.

The rest of your code can remain re-usable ( probably ) and you dont need to cope with an other project as well

EDIT:
For example you might register your current context like below:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));
```

You can create a new class, lets say

```
   public class OldDataDbContext : DbContext
{
    public OldDataDbContext(DbContextOptions<OldDataDbContext> options)
        : base(options)....
....
....
```

on that new dbContext class, register all the dbSets that you are going to read from that master db.
Then register that "new implementation of db context" with the connection string for the other database.

```
services.AddDbContext<OldDataDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:OldDatabaseConnection"));
```

Now next to your DefaultConnectionString appSetting ( or however else you might have called it, add an other line with the other connectionString, with keyName "OldDatabaseConnection" and you can use that new class just as you use the old one.

Comment: Its simple idea really. Right now for example you have a dbContext, with all your dbSets, right? You declare this in your DI setup, along with a connection string, smthing in the lines of 
services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>("SomeConnectionString")

Just make a new class, register it with the new class type and your second connection string, and register on this new type all the dbSets that belong to the seconds database schema. Then use the dbContext as you are using your current one, just inject it somewhere and use the second dbContext instead

Comment: i added some basic sample, hope it helps